# parsing string pathname with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a path string similar to:

```
/some/long/path/filename.extension
```

and I need to parse the "filename" part out in ruby

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use suffix parameter of `File.basename` method:

```
# irb
irb(main):001:0> File.basename('/some/long/path/filename.extension', '.*')
=> "filename"
irb(main):002:0> File.basename('/some/long/path/filename.v1.extension', '.*')
=> "filename.v1"
```

Ref: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M000026

Answer (score 7):

There is also the Pathname class:

```
require 'pathname'

Pathname.new("/a/b/c/d.txt").basename.to_s
=> "d.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

1. if you are looking for regex solution (as in tags), here it is:

   ```
   irb> "/some/long/path/filename.ext1.ext2".gsub(%r{.*/|\..*$},'')
   => "filename"
   ```
2. or more effective solution without regexp:

   ```
   irb> path = "/some/long/path/filename.ext1.ext2"
   => "/some/long/path/filename.extension"
   irb> filename = path[path.rindex('/')+1..-1]
   => "filename.ext1.ext2"
   ```

   and to crop the extension(s):

   - if you want to crop the last one:

     ```
     irb> filename[0,filename.rindex('.')]
     => "filename.ext1"
     ```
   - if you want to strip all the extensions (the same behaviour like the regex solution):

     ```
     irb> filename[0,filename.index('.')]
     => "filename"
     ```